# Finding the derivative of a complex (or not) function

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to find the derivative of the following function; $(1-x)^{n-k} $
i suppose I have to use the chain rule but I don't know how to use it:

let $f=1-x$ and $g=n-k$

$(f∘g)'= (f'∘g).g'$ But my problem is since g is constant, $g'=0$ therefore $(f'∘g).g'=0$

There is a problem

I would like to know how one would differentialte such a function

Comment: Your breakdown into a composite function is not correct.  Try this: $f(x) = (1-x), g(x) = x^{n-k}, (g\circ f )(x) = (1-x)^{n-k}$

Comment: @DougM can you briefly explain why $(g∘f)(x) = (1-x)∘x^{n-k} = (1-x)^{n-k}$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = 1-x\\
g(x) = x^{n-k}\\
(g\circ f)(x) = g(f(x)) = g(1-x) = (1-x)^{n-k}$

$(g\circ f)'(x) = g'(f)f'(x) = (n-k)(1-x)^{n-k-1}(-1)$